# SQL Server Query from PHP

Tags: php, sql

```
WHERE Date >= '. $_GET['start_date']. ' AND Date <= ' . $_GET['end_date']. ' AND ForteID = ' . $_GET['ForteID'];
```

I need to have ' around the $_GET['start_date'] as well as $_GET['end_date'] so my SQL query will work and not exactly sure how to get them in there!?  The ForteID one I do not need to because the values from my input page already have it there.  The dates on the other hand the fields are from a calendar date picker.  Let me know if I need to provide any other information.  Thanks in advance!

This is how it should look if I do a echo $query; in my PHP for the actual SQL Query to work:

```
WHERE Date >= '12/01/2012' AND Date <= '12/17/2012' AND ForteID = 'as7326'
```

But right now I get this:

```
WHERE Date >= 12/01/2012 AND Date <= 12/17/2012 AND ForteID = 'as7326'
```

EDIT:

This is what I have, but still no apostrophes surrounding the dates:

```
$Start_Date = $_GET['start_date'];
$End_Date = $_GET['end_date'];
$Forte_ID = $_GET['ForteID'];

$query = '  SELECT ForteID, Disposition, Cancel_Disposition, Date, appNumber, Phone_Num, Con_Number, Finance_Num, Num_Payments, ACH_CC, Post_Date, Total_Cost, Total_MP, New_MP_Amt, New_DP_Amt, Notes 
        FROM CSLogs.dbo.Logs 
        WHERE Date BETWEEN '.$Start_Date.' AND '.$End_Date.' AND ForteID = '.$Forte_ID;
```

Comment: Use PDO and pass date parameters. You don't have to worry about formatting dates.

Comment: Ok not finding anything on those two things that help me get apostrophes around the $_GET['start_date'] and $_GET['end_date'] for the sql server query

Comment: use the `"'"` string to add a quote...Or you can also write `'\''`...

Comment: Neither of those seemed to work, only got errors back.

Comment: sorry i was adding '\'' instead of just \'   Once I did that it worked

Comment: If you use parameters, you don't have to add the quotes. That's the essence of using parameters. You just tell the database: "Look, here is a date", and the database treats it as it wishes.